# Change tests directory in elm test?

Tags: elm, elm-test

I'm using Java and Maven to build my server application (see [github](https://github.com/johanhaleby/rps-axon-elm)) and typically you place source code in the folder `src/main/<language>` and tests in `src/test/<language>`.

With Elm I'm using [elm-explorations/test](https://github.com/elm-explorations/test) to run my tests (since I'm using Elm 0.19) but I cannot seem to find a way to change the test folder to `src/test/elm` instead of `tests`.

I've tried for example changing `elm.json` and adding:

```
"test-directories": [
    "src/test/elm"
  ]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. So my question is:

How can I change the folder where `elm-test` assumes the tests to be located?

Comment: The `tests` folder is hard-coded in bunch of places in https://github.com/rtfeldman/node-test-runner/blob/master/lib/elm-test.js, I'm not sure what the reason is. Can you perhaps create a `tests` symlink to your folder?

Comment: Thanks, maybe you could add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tests` folder is hard-coded in https://github.com/rtfeldman/node-test-runner/blob/master/lib/elm-test.js, I'm not sure what the reason is.

As a possible work-around you could create a `tests` symlink to your folder.

Comment: symlink doesn't seem to work, however you can instead supply a glob defining where the test files are, and they don't have to be in the `tests` folder.  For example: `elm-test 'frontend/**/*Tests.elm'`.  See discussion here: https://github.com/rtfeldman/node-test-runner/pull/306.